# Comparing multiple char arrays in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm creating a program which consists of comparing three character arrays, the code is this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

#define MAX 20

int main()
{
    char c1[MAX], c2[MAX], c3[MAX];

    cout << "Introduce array 1: ";
    cin >> c1;
    cout << "Introduce array 2: ";
    cin >> c2;
    cout << "Introduce array 3: ";
    cin >> c3;

    if (strcmp(c1, c2)==0 && strcmp(c1, c3) == 0)
    {
        cout << "The three arrays are equal" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        if (strcmp(c1, c2) != 0 && strcmp(c1, c3) != 0)
        {
            cout << "The three arrays are different" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            if (strcmp(c1, c2) == 0 && strcmp(c1, c3) != 0)
            {
                cout << "1 and 2 are equal" << endl;
            }
            else
            {
                if (strcmp(c1, c2) != 0 && strcmp(c1, c3) == 0)
                {
                    cout << "1 and 3 are equal" << endl;
                }
                else
                {
                    if ((strcmp(c1, c2) != 0) && (strcmp(c2, c3) == 0))
                    {
                        cout << "2 and 3 are equal" << endl;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The thing is that I don't know why when c2 and c3 are equal and c1 is different it tells me they're all different, in all the other cases it works fine, but I don't know what am I doing wrong.

Comment: When `c2` aand `c3` are equal, but `c1` differs you'll hit this if: `(strcmp(c1, c2) != 0 && strcmp(c1, c3) != 0)`

Comment: you program is behaving the way you wrote it. When  c2 and c3 are equal and c1 is different, then it skips the first `if` and goes in the `else`. Then, it checks if `(strcmp(c1, c2) != 0 && strcmp(c1, c3) != 0)`. This expression evaluates to True, so you get `all different!`

Comment: You call `strcmp(c1, c2)` _six_ times even though the result never changes - no wonder you're finding it hard to understand your own code. If stepping through in your debugger doesn't help, step back and write out the truth table for three specific strings, and then match it against your branches.

Comment: What I don't understand is, why would you even use char arrays in C++ (not to mention the fact that you've used `#define`)?!

Comment: It's an exercise for college

Comment: @AnonymousDeveloper Use your logic with simple `int` variables instead of char arrays.  How would you have written the code?  All `strcmp` does is do a drop-in replacement of `==`.

Answer (score 1):

Always comparing two pairs duplicates the effort – and you don't cover all possible pairs. Better:

```
if c1 == c2:
    if c2 == c3:
        all equal
    else:
        c3 differs from c1 and c2
else:
    // now c1 and c2 differ in any case!
    if c1 == c3:
        c2 differs from c1 and c3
    else:
        // c1 and c2 differ, c1 and c3 differ
        // but c2 and c3 could still be equal
        if c2 == c3:
            c1 differs from c2 and c3
        else:
            all three differ from one another
```